# Get PHP variable to check form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a php variable to send alert box to user:

```
    var filial = '<?php echo $counta; ?>';

    if (filial=='0') {  
        if (formObj.dropdown1.value=='') {  
            alert('Filial');  
            return false;  
        }  
    }
```

I think there is an error because alert is not showed...

Any tip to solve?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the output of your PHP script?  What does your JavaScript console say?  What is the value of `filial` at the `if` statement?  Also, this probably isn't your issue, but use `json_encode()` when inserting values into JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view-source and see if `filial` is initialized... Then check console for any JS errors.